# In lucene, how to find documents that contains words only from the search query

Tags: lucene

The indexed documents are:

1) experience in
2) with experience
3) with experience in
4) proficiency in
5) knowledge in
6) experience of
7) strong knowledge
8) knowledge of
9) responsible for

If my search query is "Candidates with experience in", then only first 3 documents should be retrieved. That's the documents that contains words only from the search query. For e.g., Considering 4th document, "proficiency" is not present in the search query, then it should not be retrieved.

I tried BooleanQuery with Should clause. But it returned partial match documents (4-6) also.

```
String[] searchWords = searchQuery.split(" ");
for(String searchWord: searchWords) {
 TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term("fieldName",searchWord));
 bq.add(new BooleanClause(tq, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
}
search(bq);
```

I need only documents 1-3.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a vocabulary with all possible words
2) Add must_not for all words other than that in the query.

```
ArrayList<String> searchWords = Arrays.asList(searchQuery.split(" "));
for(String searchWord: searchWords) {
 TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term("fieldName",searchWord));
 bq.add(new BooleanClause(tq, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
}
for(String word: vocabulary){
  if(!searchWords.contains(word)) {
      TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term("fieldName",word));
      bq.add(new BooleanClause(tq, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT));
  }
}
search(bq);
```

3) If looping through the vocabulary takes time, use java 8 stream features and try to optimize it.